# AirPods Pro connected to 2019 MBP; receiving end hears static

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, microphone, airpods

As you could probably tell from the title, whenever I call someone with my AirPods connected to my MacBook, the receiving end of the call hears just a super robotized voice and a very static-like sound, so bad to the point where its not understandable. This happens on all kinds of calls (Discord, FaceTime, anything) and only happens with my Mac. However, itt doesn't happen all the time but I would say occurs 80% of the time? I don't quite know what causes the other 20% to work. This problem has been occurring consistently but only on my MacBook and not on my iPhone nor my ipad, so I don't know what the problem is.